# Using Statsmodels in Python to run mixed models and use something similar to stats.anova_lm function to obtain an ANOVA (sum of squares) table

Tags: python, r, statistics, statsmodels

I'm working with `Statsmodels` to run mixed models. After getting the `summary` of my model, I would like to convert the results to an ANOVA table. However, `sm.stats.anova_lm` does not fit a mixed effect model. Does anyone know how to address this problem?

That`s the model:

```
md = smf.mixedlm("value ~ C(group) + C(time) + C(time):C(group)",
                    df_long,
                    groups= df_long["unique_id"])

mdf = md.fit()
print(mdf.summary())
```

That`s the desired output (from R)

[image: R output]

That's the data:

```
df_long = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'group': {0: 'Leave from home', 1: 'Leave from home', 2: 'Stay at home', 3: 'Stay at home', 4: 'Stay at home', 5: 'Stay at home', 6: 'Stay at home', 7: 'Stay at home', 8: 'Stay at home', 9: 'Stay at home', 10: 'Leave from home', 11: 'Leave from home', 12: 'Stay at home', 13: 'Leave from home', 14: 'Stay at home', 15: 'Stay at home', 16: 'Leave from home', 17: 'Stay at home', 18: 'Leave from home', 19: 'Leave from home', 20: 'Leave from home', 21: 'Stay at home', 22: 'Leave from home', 23: 'Leave from home', 24: 'Stay at home', 25: 'Stay at home', 26: 'Stay at home', 27: 'Stay at home', 28: 'Leave from home', 29: 'Leave from home', 30: 'Stay at home', 31: 'Leave from home', 32: 'Stay at home', 33: 'Leave from home', 34: 'Stay at home', 35: 'Leave from home', 36: 'Stay at home', 37: 'Leave from home', 38: 'Stay at home', 39: 'Stay at home', 40: 'Leave from home', 41: 'Stay at home', 42: 'Stay at home', 43: 'Leave from home', 44: 'Stay at home', 45: 'Leave from home', 46: 'Stay at home', 47: 'Stay at home', 48: 'Stay at home', 49: 'Leave from home', 50: 'Leave from home', 51: 'Stay at home', 52: 'Stay at home', 53: 'Stay at home', 54: 'Stay at home', 55: 'Leave from home', 56: 'Leave from home', 57: 'Stay at home', 58: 'Stay at home', 59: 'Leave from home', 60: 'Stay at home', 61: 'Stay at home', 62: 'Leave from home', 63: 'Leave from home', 64: 'Stay at home', 65: 'Stay at home', 66: 'Leave from home', 67: 'Stay at home', 68: 'Leave from home', 69: 'Stay at home', 70: 'Leave from home', 71: 'Stay at home', 72: 'Stay at home', 73: 'Leave from home', 74: 'Leave from home', 75: 'Stay at home', 76: 'Stay at home', 77: 'Leave from home', 78: 'Stay at home', 79: 'Leave from home', 80: 'Stay at home', 81: 'Leave from home', 82: 'Stay at home', 83: 'Stay at home', 84: 'Stay at home', 85: 'Stay at home', 86: 'Stay at home', 87: 'Leave from home', 88: 'Stay at home', 89: 'Stay at home', 90: 'Leave from home', 91: 'Stay at home', 92: 'Stay at home', 93: 'Leave from home', 94: 'Stay at home', 95: 'Stay at home', 96: 'Stay at home', 97: 'Stay at home', 98: 'Stay at home', 99: 'Stay at home', 100: 'Leave from home', 101: 'Stay at home', 102: 'Leave from home', 103: 'Stay at home', 104: 'Leave from home', 105: 'Stay at home', 106: 'Leave from home', 107: 'Leave from home', 108: 'Stay at home', 109: 'Stay at home', 110: 'Stay at home', 111: 'Stay at home', 112: 'Leave from home', 113: 'Stay at home', 114: 'Leave from home', 115: 'Stay at home', 116: 'Stay at home', 117: 'Stay at home', 118: 'Leave from home', 119: 'Leave from home', 120: 'Stay at home', 121: 'Stay at home', 122: 'Stay at home', 123: 'Stay at home', 124: 'Stay at home', 125: 'Stay at home', 126: 'Stay at home', 127: 'Stay at home', 128: 'Leave from home', 129: 'Leave from home', 130: 'Stay at home', 131: 'Leave from home', 132: 'Stay at home', 133: 'Stay at home', 134: 'Leave from home', 135: 'Stay at home', 136: 'Leave from home', 137: 'Leave from home', 138: 'Leave from home', 139: 'Stay at home', 140: 'Leave from home', 141: 'Leave from home', 142: 'Stay at home', 143: 'Stay at home', 144: 'Stay at home', 145: 'Stay at home', 146: 'Leave from home', 147: 'Leave from home', 148: 'Stay at home', 149: 'Leave from home', 150: 'Stay at home', 151: 'Leave from home', 152: 'Stay at home', 153: 'Leave from home', 154: 'Stay at home', 155: 'Leave from home', 156: 'Stay at home', 157: 'Stay at home', 158: 'Leave from home', 159: 'Stay at home', 160: 'Stay at home', 161: 'Leave from home', 162: 'Stay at home', 163: 'Leave from home', 164: 'Stay at home', 165: 'Stay at home', 166: 'Stay at home', 167: 'Leave from home', 168: 'Leave from home', 169: 'Stay at home', 170: 'Stay at home', 171: 'Stay at home', 172: 'Stay at home', 173: 'Leave from home', 174: 'Leave from home', 175: 'Stay at home', 176: 'Stay at home', 177: 'Leave from home', 178: 'Stay at home', 179: 'Stay at home', 180: 'Leave from home', 181: 'Leave from home', 182: 'Stay at home', 183: 'Stay at home', 184: 'Leave from home', 185: 'Stay at home', 186: 'Leave from home', 187: 'Stay at home', 188: 'Leave from home', 189: 'Stay at home', 190: 'Stay at home', 191: 'Leave from home', 192: 'Leave from home', 193: 'Stay at home', 194: 'Stay at home', 195: 'Leave from home', 196: 'Stay at home', 197: 'Leave from home', 198: 'Stay at home', 199: 'Leave from home', 200: 'Stay at home', 201: 'Stay at home', 202: 'Stay at home', 203: 'Stay at home', 204: 'Stay at home', 205: 'Leave from home', 206: 'Stay at home', 207: 'Stay at home', 208: 'Leave from home', 209: 'Stay at home', 210: 'Stay at home', 211: 'Leave from home', 212: 'Stay at home', 213: 'Stay at home', 214: 'Stay at home', 215: 'Stay at home', 216: 'Stay at home', 217: 'Stay at home', 218: 'Leave from home', 219: 'Stay at home', 220: 'Leave from home', 221: 'Stay at home', 222: 'Leave from home', 223: 'Stay at home', 224: 'Leave from home', 225: 'Leave from home', 226: 'Stay at home', 227: 'Stay at home', 228: 'Stay at home', 229: 'Stay at home', 230: 'Leave from home', 231: 'Stay at home', 232: 'Leave from home', 233: 'Stay at home', 234: 'Stay at home', 235: 'Stay at home'}, 'unique_id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10, 10: 11, 11: 12, 12: 13, 13: 14, 14: 15, 15: 16, 16: 17, 17: 18, 18: 19, 19: 20, 20: 21, 21: 22, 22: 23, 23: 24, 24: 25, 25: 26, 26: 27, 27: 28, 28: 29, 29: 30, 30: 31, 31: 32, 32: 33, 33: 34, 34: 35, 35: 36, 36: 37, 37: 38, 38: 39, 39: 40, 40: 41, 41: 42, 42: 43, 43: 44, 44: 45, 45: 46, 46: 47, 47: 48, 48: 49, 49: 50, 50: 51, 51: 52, 52: 53, 53: 54, 54: 55, 55: 56, 56: 57, 57: 58, 58: 59, 59: 60, 60: 61, 61: 62, 62: 63, 63: 64, 64: 65, 65: 66, 66: 67, 67: 68, 68: 69, 69: 70, 70: 71, 71: 72, 72: 73, 73: 74, 74: 75, 75: 76, 76: 77, 77: 78, 78: 79, 79: 80, 80: 81, 81: 82, 82: 83, 83: 84, 84: 85, 85: 86, 86: 87, 87: 88, 88: 89, 89: 90, 90: 91, 91: 92, 92: 93, 93: 94, 94: 95, 95: 96, 96: 97, 97: 98, 98: 99, 99: 100, 100: 101, 101: 102, 102: 103, 103: 104, 104: 105, 105: 106, 106: 107, 107: 108, 108: 109, 109: 110, 110: 111, 111: 112, 112: 113, 113: 114, 114: 115, 115: 116, 116: 117, 117: 118, 118: 1, 119: 2, 120: 3, 121: 4, 122: 5, 123: 6, 124: 7, 125: 8, 126: 9, 127: 10, 128: 11, 129: 12, 130: 13, 131: 14, 132: 15, 133: 16, 134: 17, 135: 18, 136: 19, 137: 20, 138: 21, 139: 22, 140: 23, 141: 24, 142: 25, 143: 26, 144: 27, 145: 28, 146: 29, 147: 30, 148: 31, 149: 32, 150: 33, 151: 34, 152: 35, 153: 36, 154: 37, 155: 38, 156: 39, 157: 40, 158: 41, 159: 42, 160: 43, 161: 44, 162: 45, 163: 46, 164: 47, 165: 48, 166: 49, 167: 50, 168: 51, 169: 52, 170: 53, 171: 54, 172: 55, 173: 56, 174: 57, 175: 58, 176: 59, 177: 60, 178: 61, 179: 62, 180: 63, 181: 64, 182: 65, 183: 66, 184: 67, 185: 68, 186: 69, 187: 70, 188: 71, 189: 72, 190: 73, 191: 74, 192: 75, 193: 76, 194: 77, 195: 78, 196: 79, 197: 80, 198: 81, 199: 82, 200: 83, 201: 84, 202: 85, 203: 86, 204: 87, 205: 88, 206: 89, 207: 90, 208: 91, 209: 92, 210: 93, 211: 94, 212: 95, 213: 96, 214: 97, 215: 98, 216: 99, 217: 100, 218: 101, 219: 102, 220: 103, 221: 104, 222: 105, 223: 106, 224: 107, 225: 108, 226: 109, 227: 110, 228: 111, 229: 112, 230: 113, 231: 114, 232: 115, 233: 116, 234: 117, 235: 118}, 'time': {0: 'total_ces_t1', 1: 'total_ces_t1', 2: 'total_ces_t1', 3: 'total_ces_t1', 4: 'total_ces_t1', 5: 'total_ces_t1', 6: 'total_ces_t1', 7: 'total_ces_t1', 8: 'total_ces_t1', 9: 'total_ces_t1', 10: 'total_ces_t1', 11: 'total_ces_t1', 12: 'total_ces_t1', 13: 'total_ces_t1', 14: 'total_ces_t1', 15: 'total_ces_t1', 16: 'total_ces_t1', 17: 'total_ces_t1', 18: 'total_ces_t1', 19: 'total_ces_t1', 20: 'total_ces_t1', 21: 'total_ces_t1', 22: 'total_ces_t1', 23: 'total_ces_t1', 24: 'total_ces_t1', 25: 'total_ces_t1', 26: 'total_ces_t1', 27: 'total_ces_t1', 28: 'total_ces_t1', 29: 'total_ces_t1', 30: 'total_ces_t1', 31: 'total_ces_t1', 32: 'total_ces_t1', 33: 'total_ces_t1', 34: 'total_ces_t1', 35: 'total_ces_t1', 36: 'total_ces_t1', 37: 'total_ces_t1', 38: 'total_ces_t1', 39: 'total_ces_t1', 40: 'total_ces_t1', 41: 'total_ces_t1', 42: 'total_ces_t1', 43: 'total_ces_t1', 44: 'total_ces_t1', 45: 'total_ces_t1', 46: 'total_ces_t1', 47: 'total_ces_t1', 48: 'total_ces_t1', 49: 'total_ces_t1', 50: 'total_ces_t1', 51: 'total_ces_t1', 52: 'total_ces_t1', 53: 'total_ces_t1', 54: 'total_ces_t1', 55: 'total_ces_t1', 56: 'total_ces_t1', 57: 'total_ces_t1', 58: 'total_ces_t1', 59: 'total_ces_t1', 60: 'total_ces_t1', 61: 'total_ces_t1', 62: 'total_ces_t1', 63: 'total_ces_t1', 64: 'total_ces_t1', 65: 'total_ces_t1', 66: 'total_ces_t1', 67: 'total_ces_t1', 68: 'total_ces_t1', 69: 'total_ces_t1', 70: 'total_ces_t1', 71: 'total_ces_t1', 72: 'total_ces_t1', 73: 'total_ces_t1', 74: 'total_ces_t1', 75: 'total_ces_t1', 76: 'total_ces_t1', 77: 'total_ces_t1', 78: 'total_ces_t1', 79: 'total_ces_t1', 80: 'total_ces_t1', 81: 'total_ces_t1', 82: 'total_ces_t1', 83: 'total_ces_t1', 84: 'total_ces_t1', 85: 'total_ces_t1', 86: 'total_ces_t1', 87: 'total_ces_t1', 88: 'total_ces_t1', 89: 'total_ces_t1', 90: 'total_ces_t1', 91: 'total_ces_t1', 92: 'total_ces_t1', 93: 'total_ces_t1', 94: 'total_ces_t1', 95: 'total_ces_t1', 96: 'total_ces_t1', 97: 'total_ces_t1', 98: 'total_ces_t1', 99: 'total_ces_t1', 100: 'total_ces_t1', 101: 'total_ces_t1', 102: 'total_ces_t1', 103: 'total_ces_t1', 104: 'total_ces_t1', 105: 'total_ces_t1', 106: 'total_ces_t1', 107: 'total_ces_t1', 108: 'total_ces_t1', 109: 'total_ces_t1', 110: 'total_ces_t1', 111: 'total_ces_t1', 112: 'total_ces_t1', 113: 'total_ces_t1', 114: 'total_ces_t1', 115: 'total_ces_t1', 116: 'total_ces_t1', 117: 'total_ces_t1', 118: 'total_ces_t2', 119: 'total_ces_t2', 120: 'total_ces_t2', 121: 'total_ces_t2', 122: 'total_ces_t2', 123: 'total_ces_t2', 124: 'total_ces_t2', 125: 'total_ces_t2', 126: 'total_ces_t2', 127: 'total_ces_t2', 128: 'total_ces_t2', 129: 'total_ces_t2', 130: 'total_ces_t2', 131: 'total_ces_t2', 132: 'total_ces_t2', 133: 'total_ces_t2', 134: 'total_ces_t2', 135: 'total_ces_t2', 136: 'total_ces_t2', 137: 'total_ces_t2', 138: 'total_ces_t2', 139: 'total_ces_t2', 140: 'total_ces_t2', 141: 'total_ces_t2', 142: 'total_ces_t2', 143: 'total_ces_t2', 144: 'total_ces_t2', 145: 'total_ces_t2', 146: 'total_ces_t2', 147: 'total_ces_t2', 148: 'total_ces_t2', 149: 'total_ces_t2', 150: 'total_ces_t2', 151: 'total_ces_t2', 152: 'total_ces_t2', 153: 'total_ces_t2', 154: 'total_ces_t2', 155: 'total_ces_t2', 156: 'total_ces_t2', 157: 'total_ces_t2', 158: 'total_ces_t2', 159: 'total_ces_t2', 160: 'total_ces_t2', 161: 'total_ces_t2', 162: 'total_ces_t2', 163: 'total_ces_t2', 164: 'total_ces_t2', 165: 'total_ces_t2', 166: 'total_ces_t2', 167: 'total_ces_t2', 168: 'total_ces_t2', 169: 'total_ces_t2', 170: 'total_ces_t2', 171: 'total_ces_t2', 172: 'total_ces_t2', 173: 'total_ces_t2', 174: 'total_ces_t2', 175: 'total_ces_t2', 176: 'total_ces_t2', 177: 'total_ces_t2', 178: 'total_ces_t2', 179: 'total_ces_t2', 180: 'total_ces_t2', 181: 'total_ces_t2', 182: 'total_ces_t2', 183: 'total_ces_t2', 184: 'total_ces_t2', 185: 'total_ces_t2', 186: 'total_ces_t2', 187: 'total_ces_t2', 188: 'total_ces_t2', 189: 'total_ces_t2', 190: 'total_ces_t2', 191: 'total_ces_t2', 192: 'total_ces_t2', 193: 'total_ces_t2', 194: 'total_ces_t2', 195: 'total_ces_t2', 196: 'total_ces_t2', 197: 'total_ces_t2', 198: 'total_ces_t2', 199: 'total_ces_t2', 200: 'total_ces_t2', 201: 'total_ces_t2', 202: 'total_ces_t2', 203: 'total_ces_t2', 204: 'total_ces_t2', 205: 'total_ces_t2', 206: 'total_ces_t2', 207: 'total_ces_t2', 208: 'total_ces_t2', 209: 'total_ces_t2', 210: 'total_ces_t2', 211: 'total_ces_t2', 212: 'total_ces_t2', 213: 'total_ces_t2', 214: 'total_ces_t2', 215: 'total_ces_t2', 216: 'total_ces_t2', 217: 'total_ces_t2', 218: 'total_ces_t2', 219: 'total_ces_t2', 220: 'total_ces_t2', 221: 'total_ces_t2', 222: 'total_ces_t2', 223: 'total_ces_t2', 224: 'total_ces_t2', 225: 'total_ces_t2', 226: 'total_ces_t2', 227: 'total_ces_t2', 228: 'total_ces_t2', 229: 'total_ces_t2', 230: 'total_ces_t2', 231: 'total_ces_t2', 232: 'total_ces_t2', 233: 'total_ces_t2', 234: 'total_ces_t2', 235: 'total_ces_t2'}, 'value': {0: 29, 1: 26, 2: 9, 3: 36, 4: 44, 5: 9, 6: 28, 7: 7, 8: 22, 9: 26, 10: 6, 11: 18, 12: 8, 13: 24, 14: 13, 15: 24, 16: 16, 17: 27, 18: 17, 19: 5, 20: 10, 21: 22, 22: 12, 23: 12, 24: 26, 25: 16, 26: 50, 27: 41, 28: 13, 29: 4, 30: 54, 31: 53, 32: 21, 33: 36, 34: 39, 35: 30, 36: 13, 37: 19, 38: 47, 39: 21, 40: 5, 41: 21, 42: 14, 43: 17, 44: 22, 45: 41, 46: 35, 47: 35, 48: 7, 49: 23, 50: 2, 51: 43, 52: 20, 53: 37, 54: 15, 55: 0, 56: 28, 57: 4, 58: 26, 59: 21, 60: 22, 61: 15, 62: 13, 63: 20, 64: 9, 65: 22, 66: 3, 67: 18, 68: 41, 69: 15, 70: 40, 71: 37, 72: 22, 73: 20, 74: 9, 75: 38, 76: 30, 77: 11, 78: 38, 79: 43, 80: 17, 81: 21, 82: 5, 83: 29, 84: 18, 85: 26, 86: 22, 87: 13, 88: 22, 89: 24, 90: 16, 91: 24, 92: 43, 93: 27, 94: 5, 95: 25, 96: 33, 97: 36, 98: 31, 99: 5, 100: 21, 101: 2, 102: 26, 103: 3, 104: 35, 105: 1, 106: 14, 107: 49, 108: 29, 109: 23, 110: 19, 111: 18, 112: 14, 113: 45, 114: 4, 115: 12, 116: 9, 117: 3, 118: 27, 119: 52, 120: 11, 121: 14, 122: 21, 123: 9, 124: 16, 125: 12, 126: 40, 127: 29, 128: 5, 129: 13, 130: 9, 131: 10, 132: 30, 133: 12, 134: 15, 135: 21, 136: 9, 137: 4, 138: 10, 139: 16, 140: 6, 141: 17, 142: 55, 143: 34, 144: 47, 145: 50, 146: 21, 147: 3, 148: 46, 149: 22, 150: 7, 151: 30, 152: 60, 153: 20, 154: 19, 155: 10, 156: 22, 157: 21, 158: 4, 159: 32, 160: 3, 161: 18, 162: 30, 163: 32, 164: 19, 165: 30, 166: 22, 167: 6, 168: 7, 169: 50, 170: 20, 171: 45, 172: 24, 173: 0, 174: 42, 175: 7, 176: 35, 177: 21, 178: 13, 179: 37, 180: 12, 181: 12, 182: 24, 183: 12, 184: 5, 185: 36, 186: 40, 187: 15, 188: 45, 189: 42, 190: 26, 191: 34, 192: 39, 193: 45, 194: 36, 195: 31, 196: 21, 197: 38, 198: 37, 199: 20, 200: 9, 201: 20, 202: 29, 203: 30, 204: 33, 205: 9, 206: 5, 207: 24, 208: 24, 209: 24, 210: 43, 211: 29, 212: 32, 213: 16, 214: 25, 215: 32, 216: 38, 217: 10, 218: 45, 219: 5, 220: 8, 221: 11, 222: 18, 223: 2, 224: 25, 225: 38, 226: 14, 227: 10, 228: 9, 229: 28, 230: 25, 231: 29, 232: 9, 233: 9, 234: 14, 235: 4}})
```

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. Did you ever get something like this working in Statsmodels?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is taken directly from [here](https://nicoleeic.github.io/Brain_and_Code/2019/09/02/ANOVA_new.html).

```
my_model_fit = AnovaRM(df_2way_rm, 'my_value', 'sub_id', within=['task', 'condition']).fit()
print(my_model_fit.anova_table)
```

...where `df_2way_rm` is the input DataFrame (that was passed into `mixed_lm`).

Do note that if you have "more than one observation per subject and cell" you'll need the `aggregate_func` variable ([reference](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.anova.AnovaRM.html)). The one provided option is `np.mean`. I get different results in R (with lme4) and Python when doing this. Additionally, the sum of squares and mean square are shown in the R output but do not appear in the statsmodels output.